# Chart.js label value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a question, anyone have an idea, how to change Chart.js label value format?

**Screenshot:**
[image]

How to change it, so it would show not "ACW (sec): 10" **but** "ACW: 10sec"

Code looks like:

```
var doughnutDataAcw = [
                {
                    value: <?php echo gmdate("s", $singleacw); ?>,
                    color: "#35df6b",
                    highlight: "#06cc45",
                    label: "ACW (sec)"
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tooltipTemplate` option:

```
    tooltipTemplate: "ACW: <%=value%>sec"
```

If you need the `ACW` part to come from the label:

```
    tooltipTemplate: "<%=label%>: <%=value%>sec"
```

Comment: Is it possible to have few different options? Like one for "sec" and other one for %?

Comment: @JustinasT Well you'd have to somehow make your label value contain the separate "pieces". You *might* be able to use an array for the label, but I have not tried that.